# How to store different structures with fields in two separate columns within the same structure?

Tags: matlab, struct, field

I am trying to create a structure so that I can identify what data corresponds to which file and put them side by side in two columns, like:

| file | data |
| --- | --- |
| file_10 | data_10 |
| file_20 | data_20 |
| file_30 | data_30 |
| file_40 | data_40 |

My data consists of a 1 x 30 struct with 2 fields, so my data_10 is the following:

[image]

Currently, my files names are stored as follows:

[image]

The code I have written currently is as follows:

```
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, 'latex*.mat');
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
theFiles = natsortfiles(theFiles);

data = [];
for x = 1 : length(theFiles)
   baseFileName = theFiles(x).name;
   data(x) =nk_imp_k15('ref.mat','base.mat',baseFileName);
end   %nk_imp_k15 is a function that processes the .mat data files and results in the 1x30 data structure with 2 fields above.
```

But when I do this I get the following error :

***Conversion to double from struct is not possible.***

```
Error in latex_analysis (line 19)
data(x)=nk_imp_k15('ref.mat','base.mat',baseFileName);
```

`nk_imp_15` is a custom function to process the data, that results in 1x30 structure with 2 fields.

How can I store my data and get my file names in the way shown on the table above?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. It explains not only what the error is, but also *where* it happens. This is essential to understand the problem. Also, what is `nk_imp_k15`? Google doesn't know about it, is it a function you wrote yourself? Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I forgot to explain what that nk_imp_15 is just a function developed by a colleague to process the data, that results in 1x30 structure with 2 fields.

Regarding the error, I will check that straight away.

Comment: I'm guessing that the assignment `data(x)=...` causes the error. You are writing the output of this function (a struct) into a double array. Try initializing `data = struct()`.

Comment: ...actually that doesn't work either. This used to work back in the old days, I think they've made the struct assignment more strict. You'll have to split out the first file from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm simplifying your code to:

```matlab
data = [];
for x = 1:10
   data(x) = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
end
```

This reproduces the problem. I am pretty sure that this used to be valid code, back in the day. But it doesn't run in the current version of MATLAB.
In the code below, replace `struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz')` with your function call.

A way around this error is running the function separately for the first file, then in a loop for the remainder:

```matlab
x = 1;
data = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
for x = 2:10
   data(x) = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
end
```

It's not as pretty, but it works. A slightly prettier version, but also not ideal, is:

```matlab
data = [];
for x = 1:10
   res = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
   if isempty(data)
      data = s;
   else
      data(x) = s;
   end
end
```

A prettier solution requires you know the field names that are produced by your function:

```matlab
data = struct('foo',{},'bar', {});  % This is an empty struct
for x = 1:10
   data(x) = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
end
```

Ideally you'd pre-allocate the array. This requires creating the struct array with enough elements that it doesn't need to be reallocated in every loop iteration. Pre-allocation makes code a lot more efficient. You can do it this way:

```matlab
data = struct('foo',{},'bar', {});  % create an empty struct
data(10).foo = [];                  % add 10 elements to the struct array
for x = 1:10
   data(x) = struct('foo',x, 'bar','baz');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use tables for this purpose, its much easier to filter tables and to do any statistics on the stored data. You can have many nested tables, structures, cell arrays and still have all the advantages of table functions. Here is my example (hope it helps):

```
for i=1:3
    arr=rand(10);
    save(sprintf("MyArr%d.mat",i),"arr");
end

T=struct2table(dir(cd));
T=T(T.isdir==false,:);
T.name=string(T.name);
T.folder=string(T.folder);

A=contains(T.name,'.mat');
T=T(A,:);

TArr=table;
for i=1:size(T,1)
    loadedArr=load(sprintf("%s\\%s",T.folder(i),T.name(i)));
    TArr=[TArr; table({loadedArr.arr},'VariableNames',["MyArr"])];
end
T=[T,TArr];

%Instead of theese row, you can call your function
row=2;
fprintf("File '%s' On row %d has mean value 
%0.2f\n",T.name(row),row,mean(T.MyArr{row},"all"));
```